# Android firebase crashlytics issue

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to migrate this app to android 13 and I have upgraded my app to targetVersion 33, the app builds successfully, but when I debug the app in the Logcat, I'm getting the next error:

```
 E  Could not get package user id: run-as: package not debuggable: com.ct.passenger
 E  InstallClient: Could not copy '/data/local/tmp/.studio/tmp/4615cd08/install_server' to '/data/data/com.ct.passenger/code_cache/install_server-4615cd08: out='', err='run-as: package not debuggable: com.ct.passenger                                                                                                 run-as: package not debuggable: com.ct.passenger
 E  run-as: package not debuggable: com.ct.passenger
 E  Could not get package user id: run-as: package not debuggable: com.ct.passenger
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1
Process: com.ct.passenger, PID: 11357
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callTimeout(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; in class Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder' appears in /data/app/~~xAWwFXgF7FA3cR9e5KoBog==/com.ct.passenger-lzon6hQUVqRFYtjsE_-VlA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.<clinit>(HttpRequest.java:46)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequestFactory.buildHttpRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:43)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.AbstractSpiCall.getHttpRequest(AbstractSpiCall.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

This is my build.gradle file and I have also included it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
//        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        /*Deliver all*/
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0"
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate analytics to

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$versions.google.firebase.core"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:$versions.google.firebase.crashlytics"
```

I have                         'core'       : '21.1.1',
'crashlytics': '18.3.7',